# How does gethostbyaddr work on networks without an internal DNS server?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, host

If I run `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)` in Python for example, I can get back the host name of the device with the specified IP address.

I understand that large networks have internal DNS servers to keep track of the IP host pairings, but how is this task accomplished on small home networks without an internal DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to resolve names for hosts on your LAN, you may choose to populate your hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on typical *nix systems) with static entries for your local hosts.  Generally, by default, the resolver consults the hosts file before going out to the DNS servers provided by your ISP.

If the hosts on your LAN are themselves using dynamic addressing through DHCP for address assignment, then you are facing a more dicey solution.  I tend to stick with static addressing on my house LAN for just this reason.